# How to get replaced nodes in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I'm replacing nodes in XDocument, but I can't find a simple way to access them after they were replaced. In the code below I can replace "nodeC" with "newnode", but if I try to do something with the new node, it doesn't affect the document. How can I get the actually replaced nodes?

```
var document = XDocument.Parse("<nodeA><nodeB/><nodeC/><nodeD/></nodeA>");
var oldNode = document.Descendants("nodeC").First();
var newNode = XElement.Parse("<root><newnode/></root>").Element("newnode");
oldNode.ReplaceWith(newNode);
newNode.AddBeforeSelf(new XComment("comment")); // the comment is not added
```

P.S. I can select them from the document afterwards, but I'd prefer to use something in API that will allow me to get the replaced elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `Replace`, `newNode` already has a parent - so it's cloned. If you remove it from its parent *before* calling `ReplaceWith`, then the element is added directly instead of a copy being added:

```
newNode.Remove();
oldNode.ReplaceWith(newNode);
```

... now you'll see the comment in your document.

Another option (which doesn't affect the "source" document of the node) is to manually clone the node yourself instead:

```
newNode = new XElement(newNode);
oldNode.ReplaceWith(newNode);
```

Again, `newNode` now doesn't have a parent when you call `ReplaceWith`, so it doesn't need to be cloned again, and instead is inserted directly.